# getting specific item from query answer mongodb node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was wondering if there is a way I can get a part of an object in mongo using node. For example, it would be great if I could log say the email that is being added, by using something like `console.log(result.email)` to get the email part of my response. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: When the document is removed the result only contains metadata about the transaction. It will not return any other specific information about the document that is removed. So if you want to log anything specific about the user you will have to either query the database before removing the document (not recommended) or pass any user information from the client to the server for logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found a way to do this. It will not work on the `.find` function for some reason, but will work on `.findOne` and `.sort`

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
var dbo = db.db("db");
let query = {
    username: "username",
    key: "key"
};
dbo.collection("keys").findOne(query, (function(err, result) {
    var lengthboi = result.length;
    console.log(result)
    if (lengthboi === 1) {
        //do stuff
    } else {

    }

}));
});
```